# batch for loop increment value ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Tags: batch-file, increment

I'm trying to make a simple batch-file to make 7zip-archives from all the files in it's directory.

I want the 7zip-archives to get names like **a01.7z**, **a02.7z**, **a03.7z**...

Apparently incrementing a value in a batch-for-loops isn't easy.

The setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION solution doesn't work on my computer (windows 10, 64-bit)

Someone suggested putting the increment-code in a subroutine:

```
set /a counter=0
for %%i in (*.*) do (
    call :pass2
    goto :cont
    :pass2
        set /a counter=%counter%+1
        goto :EOF
    :cont
        "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a a%counter% "%%i"
)
```

This doesn't work because somehow DOS doesn't understand the final "%%i" anymore and just outputs "%i".

Please teach me how to make a for-loop in batch with a counter.

Comment: EnabledDelayedExpansion turns on a different mode. Delayed variables are `!var!` which is a legal variable name if delayed expansion is off (the normal state). See `set /?` for help and an explanation. Note you refer to variables normally `%var%` unless you specifically want it expanded at execution time. The reason you are having an issue is your code is in brackets, meaning all those lines are treated as one line. Therefore variable expansion occurs when that block of lines are read.

Comment: Your sub routine is wrong. 1/ It is within the brackets 2/ You pass `%%I` as a parameter to the sub routine, the sub routine accesses it via `%1`. See `call /?`. 3/ You put `Goto :eof` at the end of a sub. Then your main routine then needs to jump over it (or to end via `goto :eof`). See `goto /?`.

Comment: Thanks a million for teaching me stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest way to generate two-digits numbers, with a left zero:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A counter=100
for %%i in (*.*) do (
   set /A counter+=1
   "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a a!counter:~1! "%%i"
)
```

Comment: Strangely, the setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion in this code works on my computer. I must've made a typo. Very creative on the double digit counter btw. I assume the :~1 cuts off the first digit of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=0
for %%i in (*.*) do (
        set /a counter=!counter!+1
        @echo "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a a!counter! "%%i"
)
```

This adds 1 file per zip.