# Setting variables in batch with variables in the variable being set. Something is wrong

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to set multiple variables in a loop so the amount of variables can be infinite. For example, it will ask how many variables it will set and ask for each one. then it will display them. All it says is "echo is OFF" for each variable. The variables are numbers. when I do this with CMD, it works.

I am using batch on Windows 8.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
title HANGMAN
color f0
:start1
cls
echo HANGMAN
echo -------
pause
cls
set /p LETTERS=Amount of letters:
set num=0

:a
cls
set /a num=%num%+1
set /p INSERT=%num% letter:

set %num%=%INSERT%


if %LETTERS%==%NUM% (
goto finish
) else (
goto a
)

:finish
cls
echo %INSERT%
echo %num%
echo %1%
echo %2%
echo %3%
echo %4%
echo %%num%%
pause
```

This part seems to not work:

```
set %num%=%INSERT%
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch for loop increment value ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973419/batch-for-loop-increment-value-enabledelayedexpansion)

Comment: Don't use numbers as variables. Numbers are exclusively for parameters that get passed in to the script.

Comment: @SomethingDark - That is not entirely true. You can define a variable with a name that begins with a number. You just cannot expand it within a batch file unless you use delayed expansion. On the command line it works fine. So good advice is to not use variable names that begin with a number, but it can be done.

Comment: i did this instaid: set %num%L=%INSERT% and for variable showing: !1L! until 4.   When run, it comes up with !1L! until 4, instaid of the letters.